# fabric.js error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fabricjs

I have included fabric.js (dist folder) in my rails 5 app  - `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

I have a canvas html element in my view file - view.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000">
</canvas>
</div>
```

I then access the above canvas within a javascript file in `assets/javascripts/event.js`.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
canvas.add(circle);
```

```

I get below error when I navigate to the page,

`fabric.self-85644f2….js?body=1:6519 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'style' on string 'can'
    at klass._createCanvasElement (fabric.self-85644f2….js?body=1:6519)
    at klass._createLowerCanvas (fabric.self-85644f2….js?body=1:6559)
    at klass._initStatic (fabric.self-85644f2….js?body=1:6249)
    at klass.initialize (fabric.self-85644f2….js?body=1:8496)
    at new klass (fabric.self-85644f2….js?body=1:1944)
    at event.self-e4cb5e2….js?body=1:3`

Here is my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require fabric
//= require_tree .
```

**Update**

So, the when the canvas code is wrapped within a DOM ready callback, I do see the canvas rendered now. But, I still don't know what is the right way to initialize fabric i.e the right way to wait until DOM loads and then run the fabric related code.

Apparently, this is the way to wait for DOM ready - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks. However,do I add this wrapper code in all javascript files where I access canvas?

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 50, top: 50
    });
    canvas.add(circle);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited with the correct answer.

Part 1

Document along with turbolinks needs to be loaded before fabric is initialized.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 50, top: 50
    });
    canvas.add(circle);
});
```

Part 2

You can create a reusable function like this

in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
var canvas = $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        new fabric.Canvas('can');
    });
```

Using the canvas variable you can call the initialized fabric function where ever you want. Like below

```
var circle = canvas.Circle({
    radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 50, top: 50
});
canvas.add(circle);
```

Comment: I removed the inline style assignment, didn't help. fabric is okay with the element id without the '#' - http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#canvas. Appreciate your effort. My guess its something to do with the order of javascript files included or the dom being not ready when the javascript code executes.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
canvas.add(circle);
});`

I think this should work.

Comment: as suspected, it was something to do with dom init. When I added wrapped the code within dom ready call back, the canvas does get rendered. However, I don't know what is the right way to initialize fabric now. I have up-voted your comment.

Comment: Looks like this is the way to wait for DOM ready in rails - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks

Comment: I just read up on Fabric Documentation.. It clearly states that you need to initialize a fabric on a element with an id [link](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#objects)

Which in your case, you have a canvas element with id as canvas so reference the element and it should work `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');`

Comment: also as per rails guides its using coffeescript which when translated to normal Javascript is same as the upvoted comment. You can choose either to use JS or CoffeeScript. Try http://js2.coffee/

Comment: I was using the right id to start with . About the load event, the rubyonrails site (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks) says this "However, because Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process, the event that this relies on (i.e jquery document ready) will not be fired. If you have code that looks like this, you must change your code to do this (use the turbolink load) instead:".  I got confused by this statement. I am still a noob to rails, learning something new everyday.

Comment: Same here.. So you could just disable turbolinks by removing it from your js tag in application layout and application js and hopefully things should work normally.

Comment: please edit your answer with the load event, I will accept it.